# Question about moment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, vectors

Question:A uniform square block is pushed along a 
rough surface at constant speed by a force of 
100 N. A horizontal force of friction acts 
between the surface and the block. 
What is the moment of the force of friction 
about the centre of gravity?

I'm confused that how can we know the moment of friction without knowing the point or the perpendicular distance from which the 100N force is applied.

Comment: Would you mind adding the linked text here as well?

Comment: Please always make your questions self-contained, i.e., not depending on internet links/resources. Further, you might want to read [http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange](this) about how to ask homework-like questions and please refrain from using the mathematical physics tag - this is clearly not applicable.

Comment: @Sanya I thought that vectors might might've been involved so tagged it as such.Also I was genuinely confused with regards to this question, and am studying privately with no teachers so I asked about it here. I apologize for causing any trouble or inconvenience.

Comment: I don't find this off topic as a homework question - seems as a physics confusion here, so perfectly on topic. Just please don't force people to click on links.

Comment: You did not cause trouble or inconvenience and I apologise if I came across as harsh. We do have a different usage of the term "homework" here - see the link in the earlier comment. And mathematical physics is really about the mathematical structure of physical theories ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't ask about the 100 N push force. It only asks for the moment of friction, **around the centre of gravity** (CoM). That is the very middle for a uniform square-shaped box.

So now take the usual moment formula and plug in the force (of friction in this case) and the perpendicular distance (half the height I  this case).

Comment: @user134505 You are very welcome. Have a good weekend